# Is it a good idea to disable short filenames on Windows 7 running on a SSD drive?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

http://oreilly.com/pub/a/windows/2005/02/08/NTFS_Hacks.html

> By default, NTFS creates an 8.3 filename every time it creates a long filename, which adds a bit of time to the file creation process.

One can disable that using:

```
fsutil behavior set disable8dot3 1
```

Is it a good idea to do it on a Windows 7 machine running on a SSD drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

16 bit apps use 8.3 filenames.

By far the most prominent 16 bit apps are Setup programs. Not a lot of them, but some.

Like any setting, I'd test all your applications just in case.  But for the most part, you should be ok.

Comment: 8.3 can be handy when you are trying to remove a file which somehow  came to  have invalid characters in its filename.

Comment: Much truth in your statement, but beware the Dark Side of the Force!

Comment: I haven't seen a 16-bit installer in the wild in years. There had been those ancient InstallShield things that had a 16-bit installer engine but they're quite died out by now. Not to mention that 64-bit systems are increasingly common and no 16-bit process runs on those anyway.